# How to make elements show and hide in push-menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can you tell me how can I make on first click elements inside the '.push-menu-inside' move from left to right with some transition and then on second click, when closing the push-menu to make them fade out, something like fade out transition or when it is clicked to move from their own position to the left?

link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euds0n6x/1/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.push-button').click(function () {
            $('.push-button-top').toggleClass('open');
            $('.push-button-middle-under').toggleClass('open-2');
            $('.push-button-middle').toggleClass('open-1');
            $('.push-button-bottom').toggleClass('open-3');
       });
    });


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".push-button").click(function () {
                $("#push-menu").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".push-button").click(function () {
            $('.link-item-1').toggleClass('active-1');
            $('.link-item-2').toggleClass('active-2');
            $('.link-item-3').toggleClass('active-3');
            $('.link-item-4').toggleClass('active-4');
            $('.link-item-5').toggleClass('active-5');
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".push-button").click(function () {
            $('#push-button').toggleClass('activated');
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please take a look at the http://jsfiddle.net/euds0n6x/1/ not at the code alone!! Because the code is taken from the fiddle